# PyCharm IDE "warning" Expected type 'WebDrivers', got 'iPhoneTests' instead

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pytest

My script works but I'm just trying to figure it out how I can fix this warning. IDE is PyCharm

[image]

test_GoogleSearch.py

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pytest
from Framework.DriverMethods import WebDrivers


@pytest.mark.usefixtures("setup")
class iPhoneTests(object):

    def test_makeQuery(self):
        WebDrivers.sendData(self, By.XPATH, "//input[@name='q']", "Android")
```

DriverMethods.py

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pytest

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("setup")
class WebDrivers:

    def sendData(self, locator, value, data):
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30)
        try:
            element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((locator, value)))
            element.send_keys(data)
            element.submit()
        except Exception as ex:
            print(ex)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to pass `self` into the function call. That's actually it. `self` in methods will be automatically passed with an object instance, you don't have to explicitly pass something into it.

Answer (score 0):

I finally had it fixed. Added "class iPhoneTests(**WebDrivers**):"

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("setup")
class iPhoneTests(WebDrivers):

    def test_makeQuery(self):
        WebDrivers.sendData(self, By.XPATH, "//input[@name='q']", "Android")
```